# Batch - IF EXIST statement not executing

Tags: batch-file

I'm creating a batch file to automate some backups.  I've been out of the DOS / batch game for several years and I'm pretty rusty.  I'm sure my problem is pretty minor, but I can't seem to get my if statement to do anything.  Below is the offending line:

```
IF EXIST %dirname% (echo Directory already exists) ELSE (mkdir %dirname%)
::dirname in this particular case is: Backup 2013-06-06
::The directory does exist, so the echo statement should execute.
```

My echo statement, even though the condition is met, isn't triggering.  This line works fine when typed into the command prompt, but not from the .bat.  Anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "quote the name" bcause it contains a space

```
IF EXIST "%dirname%" (echo Directory already exists) ELSE (mkdir "%dirname%")
```

although

```
mkdir "%dirname%" 2>nul
```

would also work - it simply suppresses the error message output on `STDERR` (device `2`)

Comment: That did the trick!  I knew it was simple, but for some reason, it was escaping me.  (I did know about the 2>nul bit.  My IF statement will end up being far more complicated now that I'm back to work on it).  Thanks!